# Cannot access slots in child component's dynamic function in vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am passing `<slot name="success-mark">` to child component as below.

```
<vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone"
  id="dropzone"
  :options="dropzoneOptions">
  <slot name="success-mark"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></slot>
</vue-dropzone>
```

and my child component has following function which returns the template which consist above provided `slot`.

```
setPreviewTemplate(){
  return `
            <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
                <div slot="image" class="dz-image" style="width: ${this.options.thumbnailWidth}px;height: ${this.options.thumbnailHeight}px">
                <img slot="thumbnail" data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
                <div slot="details" class="dz-details">
                    <div slot="size" class="dz-size"><span data-dz-size></span></div>
                    <div slot="name" class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div>
                </div>
                <div slot="progress" class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div>
                <div slot="error-message" class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                <div class="dz-success-mark" slot="success-mark"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                <div slot="error-mark" class="dz-error-mark"></div>
            </div>
        `;
}
```

I tried multiple ways to change `slot - success-mark` but no luck.

#### Expected Behaviour

Child component should show `fa fa-trash` i.e. trash icon.

#### Actual Behaviour

Child component doesn't change the slot `success-mark` to `fa fa-trash` it remains to default `fa fa-check` i.e. check icon.

Where is the mess?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the child template to

```
<slot name="success-mark"></slot><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
```

should allow fa-trash to show (at least with non-dynamic template, it works)

Out of curiosity, could you please show how you're using the result of setPreviewTemplate()? If I understand correctly, this is a child filling it's own slot (not parent providing slot content). Or is *'and my child component has following function'* a typo, you meant to say *'and my parent component...'*?

***Edit #1***

After perusing the source [vue-dropzone](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone), one idea springs to mind (but may not be how you want to handle it) - add the icon to dropzoneOptions.

```
setPreviewTemplate(){
  return `
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
       ...
       <div class="dz-success-mark" slot="success-mark">
         <i class="fa" :class="this.options.icon"></i>
       </div>
       ...
}
```

***Edit #2***

Forgive me if I've completely misunderstood, but it looks like you have the  syntax the wrong way round.
The `<slot>` should be on the child, so I'd expect to see it in the value returned from setPreviewTemplate().
The parent provides some content which should have the slot attribute, so maybe

```
<vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone"
  id="dropzone"
  :options="dropzoneOptions">
  <i class="fa fa-trash" slot="success-mark"></i>
</vue-dropzone>
```

and

```
setPreviewTemplate(){
  return `
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
       ...
       <slot name="success-mark"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></slot>
       ...
}
```

Comment: Sure! You can see the demo [here](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/dist/index.html). It didn't worked as you suggested as I already tried it

Comment: Nice, apart from the lack of icon. Could you please post the code that uses setPrevieTemplate()?

Comment: Ok, I got it... will take a look

Comment: Don't know but it really doesn't work by changing as you suggested.

Comment: Ok, I'll set up a test shortly.

Comment: This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/OxvPQK) shows parent-child slots in action.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you're using **setPreviewTemplate()**, but in your github project you are passing **previewTemplate** to Dropzone as a function that returns a string, so you probably can't do that when there are slots involved (Vue doesn't manage the internals of Dropzone).

Comment: To allow Vue to manage the slots, the template text could go into the template property of child component, and you could extract it in setPreviewTemplate() with `this.$el.innerHTML` (or variant of this).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The approach you suggested is correct and as per your clarification I can't use slots there because `template` is returned as string and can't be handled by dropzone.